# Dolphin error opening folder as root. Linux mint 18.3 KDE

Tags: linux-mint, kde, dolphin

After first "Open as root" I've got error:

> The process for the file protocol died unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open file in text editor: `/usr/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/mint_root_dolphin.desktop`
2. Find `Exec=...` at the end
3. Replace to: `Exec=kdesudo -c "KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5 KDE_FULL_SESSION=true dbus-launch dolphin %U"`
4. Save, enjoy :)